# django jsignature not saving to database

Tags: django, model, jsignature

i am trying to implement a jsignature plug in to my django appplication via django-jsignature3 , however it seems that i am unable to get it to save to my database.

here is my code:

models.py

```
class JSignatureModel(JSignatureFieldsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
form = SignatureForm(request.POST or None)
print('in view')
if form.is_valid():
    signature = form.cleaned_data.get('signature')
    print('form is valid')
    if signature:
        # as an image
        print('found sig')
        signature_picture = draw_signature(signature)
        # or as a file
        signature_file_path = draw_signature(signature, as_file=True)
return render(request, 'cash/jsig.html', {'form': form })
```

jsig.html

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{%load crispy_forms_tags%}
{% block content %}


<body>

    {{ form.media }}
    <form action="." method="POST">

        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
            <span style="color:red">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>

</body>
{%endblock content%}
```

url.py

```
    path('jsig/', views.my_view , name='jsig')
```

forms.py (this is really iffy to me , i don't understand the documentation , there is no place that my model was called , hence i did this my self but it does not work)

```
class SignatureForm(forms.Form):
signature = JSignatureField()
class Meta:
    model = JSignatureModel
    fields = ['name','signature']
    exclude = []
```

here is my console

```
    [04/Apr/2020 01:14:43] "GET /jsig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5593
in view
form is valid
found sig
[04/Apr/2020 01:14:46] "POST /jsig/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5959
```

Please help , im really confused!

Comment: you are not calling **`form.save()`** anywhere, are you?

Comment: No , i tried that early but it throws the error : 'SignatureForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @neowenshun `SignatureForm` needs to be a subclass of `forms.ModelForm`

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you this was what i needed ! You are of great help sir